# JFX No Scrollbar when in BorderPane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to layout a table within a borderpane. When I do so, shrinking the window truncates the table and does not show a scrollbar.

This is the layout:

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication1.SimpleUIController">
<center>
<AnchorPane>
      <TableView fx:id="table" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="1000.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="colName" prefWidth="500.0" text="Name" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="colPrice" prefWidth="400.0" text="Price" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
</AnchorPane>
</center>
</BorderPane>
```

And this is what it looks like with the window made smaller than the table:[image]

If I remove the border pane like so:

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication1.SimpleUIController">
      <TableView fx:id="table" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="1000.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="colName" prefWidth="500.0" text="Name" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="colPrice" prefWidth="400.0" text="Price" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
</AnchorPane>
```

Then I get scroll bars as desired:[image]

How can I get scrollbars when using a borderpane?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ScrollPane as the parent node as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<HBox
    maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <VBox
            maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
            maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
            HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
            <children>
                <ScrollPane
                    fitToHeight="true"
                    fitToWidth="true"
                    maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
                    VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <content>
                        <BorderPane
                            maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                            maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
                            minHeight="-Infinity"
                            minWidth="-Infinity">
                            <center>
                                <TableView
                                    maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                    maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
                                    <columns>
                                        <TableColumn
                                            maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                            prefWidth="400.0"
                                            text="C1" />
                                        <TableColumn
                                            maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
                                            prefWidth="500.0"
                                            text="C2" />
                                    </columns>
                                    <columnResizePolicy>
                                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                                    </columnResizePolicy>
                                </TableView>
                            </center>
                        </BorderPane>
                    </content>
                </ScrollPane>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </children>
</HBox>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That looks close to what I need, however, if I enlarge the window the table does not use the available space. I just have lots of empty space around the table. Can I avoid that?

Comment: @zorro2b Try the updated code? It's a little message to have that many layers of wrapping, but will hopefully work.